# Do crop sensors increase the depth of field when using full frame lenses?

Tags: aperture, depth-of-field, full-frame, cropped-sensor

I'm trying to achieve maximum depth of field without sacrificing light. I have a micro-4/3rds camera and i want to attach a full frame lens to it for the large and constant aperture. My question is, will the depth of field be increased in this case, compared to the lens on a full frame camera with the same aperture?

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'increased' depth of field. Depth of field increase in full-frame cameras is a function of the sensor size, not the lenses. See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12098/why-does-a-bigger-sensor-lead-to-a-shallower-depth-of-field/12099#12099

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a smaller sensor's "crop factor" be used to calculate the exact increase in depth of field?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10079/can-a-smaller-sensors-crop-factor-be-used-to-calculate-the-exact-increase-in-d)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the same print size and effectively the same resolution, yes. But this isn't magic — it's the exact same increase you'd get by shooting with the same lens on full-frame and cropping by the corresponding amount.

Comment: There will also be no benefit of using a full-frame lens over using a lens with the same aperture designed for micro-4/3rds.

Comment: I don't understand this answer - a crop of a picture does not alter the DOF, unless you mean physical "cropping" by moving the camera or zooming?

Comment: @Console: no, I mean literal cropping. But this only applies assuming you view or print at the same size.

Comment: Thanks for commenting Matt. I consider DOF to be simply the distance between the closest and furthest part of the subject that are sharp, and this doesn't change when cropping the final image. I guess there could be a perceived difference depending on the resolution of the sensor, but a smaller sensor can have more pixels than a large one so in that case it's not actually related to the size of the sensor, is it? If you could elaborate a little or give a pointer to more information I'd appreciate it, but I realise this is an old question.

Comment: @Console: take a look at [this answer](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/10121/1943) and the Wikipedia article it links to, and also at the math-heavy second section of [this answer](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9624/what-exactly-determines-depth-of-field/9626#9626).

Comment: That was an eye-opener. My understanding of the concepts were simplistic and there is more to it than I knew. I still have some thinking to do to figure out if/how the sensor resolution affects this but you have given me the rope I need to...uhm wrong saying, but you get the idea. ;) Thanks! To other readers: Please ignore my previous comments and listen to mattdm!