# how does full frame cameras give better bokeh than crop sensor?

Tags: sensor, depth-of-field, blur, sensor-size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do the differences between APS-C and full frame sensors matter, and why?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/when-do-the-differences-between-aps-c-and-full-frame-sensors-matter-and-why)
>   [Why does a bigger sensor lead to a shallower depth of field?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12098/why-does-a-bigger-sensor-lead-to-a-shallower-depth-of-field)

When I compare my camera which is dx (crop body) and to a friend's canon 5d mk2 it seems to give a lot more blur to the image. Why?

Answer (score 6):

Short answer (because I'm sure this has been answered but I can't find a really good example):

With FF to fill the frame with your subject you have to either

- get closer (which means focussing closer, hence shallower depth of field, more blur)

Or

- use a longer focal length. Which means a larger physical aperture for a given focal length, hence more blur